# Tree Structure and Recursion

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Using a PostgreSQL 8.4.14 database, I have a table representing a tree structure like the following example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE unit (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    parent_id bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES unit (id)
);
INSERT INTO unit VALUES (1, 'parent', NULL), (2, 'child', 1)
                      , (3, 'grandchild A', 2), (4, 'grandchild B', 2);
```

```
 id |    name      | parent_id 
----+--------------+-----------
  1 | parent       |          
  2 | child        |         1
  3 | grandchild A |         2
  4 | grandchild B |         2
```

I want to create an Access Control List for those units, where each unit may have it's own ACL, or is inheriting it from the nearest ancestor with an own ACL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE acl (
    unit_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (unit_id) REFERENCES unit (id)
);
INSERT INTO acl VALUES (1), (4);
```

```
 unit_id 
---------
       1
       4
```

I'm using a view to determine if a unit is inheriting it's ACL from an ancestor:

```sql
CREATE VIEW inheriting_acl AS
    SELECT u.id AS unit_id, COUNT(a.*) = 0 AS inheriting
    FROM unit AS u
    LEFT JOIN acl AS a ON a.unit_id = u.id
    GROUP BY u.id;
```

```
 unit_id | inheriting 
---------+------------
       1 | f
       2 | t
       3 | t
       4 | f
```

**My question is:** how can I get the nearest unit which is *NOT* inheriting the ACL from an ancestor? My expected result should look similar to the following table/view:

```
 unit_id | acl 
---------+------------
       1 | 1
       2 | 1
       3 | 1
       4 | 4
```

Comment: +1 Very nice question. As *always*, your version of PostgreSQL should be included.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A query with a [**recursive CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) could do the job. Requires PostgreSQL **8.4** or later:

```
WITH RECURSIVE next_in_line AS (
    SELECT u.id AS unit_id, u.parent_id, a.unit_id AS acl
    FROM   unit u
    LEFT   JOIN acl a ON a.unit_id = u.id

    UNION  ALL
    SELECT n.unit_id, u.parent_id, a.unit_id
    FROM   next_in_line n
    JOIN   unit u ON u.id = n.parent_id AND n.acl IS NULL
    LEFT   JOIN acl a ON a.unit_id = u.id
    )
SELECT unit_id, acl
FROM   next_in_line
WHERE  acl IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY unit_id
```

The break condition in the second leg of the `UNION` is `n.acl IS NULL`. With that, the query stops traversing the the tree as soon as an `acl` is found.
In the final `SELECT` we only return the rows where an `acl` was found. Voilá.

As an aside: It is an anti-pattern to use the generic, non-descriptive `id` as column name. Sadly, some ORMs do that by default. Call it `unit_id` and you don't have to use aliases in queries all the time.