# Loop in function does not work as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, plpgsql, common-table-expression

Using PostgreSQL 9.0.4

Below is a very similar structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE departamento
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  master_fk bigint,
  nome character varying(100) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT departamento_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT departamento_master_fk_fkey FOREIGN KEY (master_fk)
      REFERENCES departamento (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

And the function I created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_retornar_dptos_ate_raiz(bigint[])
  RETURNS bigint[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   lista_ini_dptos ALIAS FOR $1;
   dp_row departamento%ROWTYPE;
   dpto bigint;
   retorno_dptos bigint[];
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      PERFORM id FROM tbl_temp_dptos;
      EXCEPTION 
         WHEN undefined_table THEN
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_temp_dptos (id bigint NOT NULL) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
   END;

   FOR i IN array_lower(lista_ini_dptos, 1)..array_upper(lista_ini_dptos, 1) LOOP
      SELECT id, master_fk INTO dp_row FROM departamento WHERE id=lista_ini_dptos[i];
      IF dp_row.id IS NOT NULL THEN
         EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tbl_temp_dptos VALUES ($1)' USING dp_row.id;
         WHILE dp_row.master_fk IS NOT NULL LOOP
            dpto := dp_row.master_fk;
            SELECT id, master_fk INTO dp_row FROM departamento WHERE id=lista_ini_dptos[i];
            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tbl_temp_dptos VALUES ($1)' USING dp_row.id;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN ARRAY(SELECT id FROM tbl_temp_dptos);
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Any questions about the names I can translate ..

What is the idea of the function? I first check if the temporary table already exists (perform), and when the exception occurs I create a temporary table.

Then I take each element in the array and use it to fetch the id and master_fk of a department. If the search is successful (check if id is not null, it is even unnecessary) I insert the id in the temporary table and start a new loop.

The second loop is intended to get all parents of that department which was previously found by performing the previous steps (ie, pick a department and insert it into the temporary table).

At the end of the second loop returns to the first. When this one ends I return bigint[] refers to what was recorded in the temporary table.

My problem is that the function returns me the same list I provide. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The select from the second loop should be `... WHERE id=dpto`. And you should have an infinite loop, unless master_fk is null for the list of ids you supplied.

Comment: If I got that right you have one department that "belongs" to other, and given an array of `bigint` you want the departments and its parents? Is that so?

Comment: @MatheusOI, the structure is based on the relationship of parents and children. A department can be a father (to be referred to as master_fk) of another. The function aims to provide all parents related to the ids in the list provided (bigint []).

Comment: @Nicolas, based on my answer to MatheusOI, the second loop will fetch the parent department (using the "master_fk" of the department son) and add the father in the temporary table. If master_fk is null, then the second loop stops because I found the root department.

I do not know if I'm being explanatory enough ... If you want I can make a flow chart to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *a lot* I would do differently, and to great effect.

### Table definition

Starting with the table definition and naming conventions. These are mostly just opinions:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE conta (conta_id bigint primary key, ...);

CREATE TEMP TABLE departamento (
   dept_id   serial PRIMARY KEY
 , master_id int REFERENCES departamento (dept_id)
 , conta_id  bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES conta (conta_id)
 , nome      text NOT NULL
);
```

#### Major points

- Are you sure you need a [`bigserial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) for departments? There are hardly that many on this planet. A plain [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) should suffice.
- I hardly ever use [`character varying`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) with a length restriction. Unlike with some other RDBMS there is no performance gain whatsoever by using a restriction. Add a `CHECK` constraint if you really need to enforce a maximum length. I just use [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html), mostly [and save myself the trouble.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)
- I suggest a naming convention where the foreign key column shares the name with the referenced column, so `master_id` instead of `master_fk`, etc. Also allows to use `USING` in joins.
- And I *rarely* use the non-descriptive column name `id`. Using `dept_id` instead here.

### PL/pgSQL function

It can be largely simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_retornar_plpgsql(lista_ini_depts VARIADIC int[])
  RETURNS int[] AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _row departamento;                     -- %ROWTYPE is just noise
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (                           -- simpler in 9.1+, see below
    SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
    WHERE  relnamespace = pg_my_temp_schema()
    AND    relname      = 'tbl_temp_dptos') THEN

   CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_temp_dptos (dept_id bigint NOT NULL)
   ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
END IF;

FOR i IN array_lower(lista_ini_depts, 1)  -- simpler in 9.1+, see below
      .. array_upper(lista_ini_depts, 1) LOOP
   SELECT *  INTO _row                    -- since rowtype is defined, * is best
   FROM   departamento
   WHERE  dept_id = lista_ini_depts[i];

   CONTINUE WHEN NOT FOUND;

   INSERT INTO tbl_temp_dptos VALUES (_row.dept_id);

   LOOP
      SELECT *  INTO _row
      FROM   departamento
      WHERE  dept_id = _row.master_id;

      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

      INSERT INTO tbl_temp_dptos
      SELECT _row.dept_id
      WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM tbl_temp_dptos
         WHERE dept_id =_row.dept_id);
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;

RETURN ARRAY(SELECT dept_id FROM tbl_temp_dptos);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_retornar_plpgsql(2, 5);
```

Or:

```
SELECT f_retornar_plpgsql(VARIADIC '{2,5}');
```

- `ALIAS FOR $1` is outdated syntax and [discouraged](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS). Use function parameters instead.
- The **`VARIADIC`** parameter makes it more convenient to call. Related:

  - [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)
- You don't need `EXECUTE` for queries without dynamic elements. Nothing to gain here.
- You don't need exception handling to create a table. Quoting the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING):

  > Tip: A block containing an `EXCEPTION` clause is significantly more
  >   expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't
  >   use `EXCEPTION` without need.
- Postgres 9.1 or later has [`CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766046/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists/7438222#7438222). I use a workaround for 9.0 to conditionally create the temp table.
- Postgres 9.1 also offer [`FOREACH` to loop through an arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214392/plpgsql-iterating-over-integer/10214621#10214621).

All that said, here comes the bummer: **you don't need most of this.**

### SQL function with rCTE

Even in Postgres 9.0, a [**recursive CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) makes this **a whole lot simpler**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_retornar_sql(lista_ini_depts VARIADIC int[])
  RETURNS int[] AS
$func$
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT dept_id, master_id
   FROM   unnest($1) AS t(dept_id)
   JOIN   departamento USING (dept_id)

   UNION ALL
   SELECT d.dept_id, d.master_id
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   departamento d ON d.dept_id = cte.master_id
   )
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT dept_id FROM cte)    -- distinct values
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Same call.

Closely related answer with explanation:

- [Tree Structure and Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184334/tree-structure-and-recursion/13185413#13185413)

[**SQL Fiddle demonstrating both.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7d48f/1)

Comment: Here are some questions:  
1 - Regarding the use of "recursive CTE," I came to find your other answer during my research, but I did not understand the answer and could not replicate, so I preferred to use a function. The issue is that I still do not understand the recursion you suggest. Sorry for my ignorance, but could you explain?  
2 - Because of the structure of my table I have to use bigint, but in your answer "lista_ini_depts" is of type int [] and you return int []. This does not generate conflicts? I thought Postgres had problem with int and bigint without explicit conversion.

Comment: @ThCC: 1 - [There is an extensive "readme" on (recursive) CTEs in the Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/CTEReadme). 2 - If you are working with `bigint` use `bigint[]`, of course. My example builds on my table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my code. At the end of this response is its final form, but if you have any suggestions for improvement are welcome. Here are the changes:

1 - I have provided the essential structure of my table, but in reality it is much bigger. Before master_fk field, there is a field called account_fk, and because of the variable department `dp_row%**ROWTYPE**` the entire structure of my table is copied to the variable, so if I fill only the first two fields, i.e., id and account_fk, then master_fk that is the third field will be null.

2 - @Nicolas was right, and I ended up using the variable dpto for the second loop. And I had forgotten to fill it inside the loop. Besides using it in the search done within the loop.

3 - I added an if statement to make sure that would not have duplicates in the temporary table.

Correction in the structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE departamento
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  account_fk bigint NOT NULL,
  master_fk bigint,
  nome character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT departamento_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT departamento_account_fk_fkey FOREIGN KEY (account_fk)
      REFERENCES conta (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT departamento_master_fk_fkey FOREIGN KEY (master_fk)
      REFERENCES departamento (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

My function as it is now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_retornar_dptos_ate_raiz(bigint[]) RETURNS bigint[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   lista_ini_dptos ALIAS FOR $1;
   dp_row departamento%ROWTYPE;
   dpto bigint;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      PERFORM id FROM tbl_temp_dptos;
      EXCEPTION 
         WHEN undefined_table THEN
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_temp_dptos (id bigint NOT NULL) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
   END;

   FOR i IN array_lower(lista_ini_dptos, 1)..array_upper(lista_ini_dptos, 1) LOOP
      SELECT id, conta_fk, master_fk INTO dp_row FROM departamento WHERE id=lista_ini_dptos[i];
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tbl_temp_dptos VALUES ($1)' USING dp_row.id;
      dpto := dp_row.master_fk;
--       RAISE NOTICE 'dp_row: (%); ', dp_row.master_fk;
      WHILE dpto IS NOT NULL LOOP
         SELECT id, conta_fk, master_fk INTO dp_row FROM departamento WHERE id=dpto;
         IF NOT(select exists(select 1 from tbl_temp_dptos where id=dp_row.id limit 1)) THEN
            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tbl_temp_dptos VALUES ($1)' USING dp_row.id;
         END IF;
         dpto := dp_row.master_fk;
--   RAISE NOTICE 'dp_row: (%); ', dp_row.master_fk;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN ARRAY(SELECT id FROM tbl_temp_dptos);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```