# Inserting values into array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to insert values into an integer array, used as path to show all ancestors of a particular node.

These values (`parent_link integer`) are from a table with ID and `parent_link`. I am trying to traverse the tree-like structure to assemble all `parent_link` in a path to insert into an integer array belonging to that particular ID. I am trying to do this for every single record in my database. So far I have:

```
INSERT INTO master_ifis_network (path)
SELECT t2.parent_link
FROM master_ifis_network as t2
WHERE t2.parent_link = (SELECT t1.parent_link
     FROM master_ifis_network as t1)
AND t2.link_id = (parent_link)
```

I get an error saying that I cannot insert an `integer` where an `integer[]` is expected.
I have also tried this, which outputs a list of the parent nodes:

```
SELECT parentX.parent_link FROM [table name] as nodeX, [table name] as parentx
WHERE nodeX.left BETWEEN parentX.left AND parentX.right)
AND nodeX.link_id = [some id] 
ORDER BY parentX.left DESC
```

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: I'm not getting how SQL Server will expect "integer[]" value to insert into a field.

Am I missing something? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: the column I want to enter all my data is a integer[]

Comment: What Database Engine are you using?

Comment: What is the exact error message and the `master_ifis_network` schema?

Comment: A question like this *needs* a table definition (what you get with `\d tbl` in `psql`) and the exact version of Postgres.

Comment: @celerno [tag:sql] doesn't means [tag:ms-sql-server], it means *"the structured query language, SQL"*. Please don't buy into the confusion Microsoft created with their confusing product naming by assuming that "SQL" means "MS SQL Server".

Comment: Question didn't include tags and comments when i asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive CTE, i.e.: `WITH RECURSIVE`.
And you need an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT link_id, ARRAY[parent_link] AS path, 1 AS level
   FROM   master_ifis_network

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT c.link_id, m.parent_link || c.path, c.level + 1
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   master_ifis_network m ON m.link_id = c.path[1]
   )
UPDATE master_ifis_network m
SET    path = sub.path
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (link_id) *
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY link_id, level DESC
  ) sub
WHERE m.link_id = sub.link_id;
```

Related answers:

- [Tree Structure and Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184334/tree-structure-and-recursion/13185413#13185413)
- [Recursive query used for transitive closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979831/recursive-query-used-for-transitive-closure/20983666#20983666)

There are many others here. Search with above key words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
UPDATE master_ifis_network SET path = array(SELECT parentX.parent_link 
FROM master_ifis_network AS parentX 
WHERE (nodeX.left BETWEEN parentX.left AND parentX.right) AND nodeX.link_id = [some id] 
ORDER BY parentX.left DESC) 
WHERE link_id = [same id];"
```